# C# Renew certificate issued by CA

Tags: c#, x509certificate, ca, renewal

I'm trying to renew an existing certificate issued by my personal CA.

The problem is that I can't do it from the server that uses the certificate and therefore i have no access to the private key.

However, I do have the CSR used to create the original certificate (the CSR was created on the server that has the private key).

Is there any way to renew the certificate only with the original CSR itself and the current certificate? (I know it's bad practice and i should use a new CSR but in this case i have no other option).

In using CertEnroll to create the request and communicate with the Microsoft CA.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: The certificate is signed and any editing would require resigning the certificate.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. I want to renew the certificate (to extend the validity period).

Comment: The certificate has an expiration date which is included in the signing section of the certificate.  So if you change the expiration date the signed section is no longer valid.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the expiration date on the existing certificate. I want to renew the certificate and therefore issue a new certificate.

Comment: You can't renew the certificate if it has an expiration date that has past.

Comment: The certificate is not expired yet, it will be soon and therefore i want to renew it.

Comment: `I'm trying to renew an existing certificate issued by my personal CA.` -- follow the procedures you used to enroll original certificate.

Comment: The problem is that the template has issuance requirements that require the request to be signed by unique certificate with unique OID. In issuance process I have the required OID but when I renew i don't have it. So i want to renew the certificate based on existing certificate. The template is configured to have different issuance requirements for regular issuance and renew request.

Comment: Then you need to use `IX509CertificateRequestPkcs7::InitializeFromCertificate` method to perform renewal: https://learn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/windows/win32/api/certenroll/nf-certenroll-ix509certificaterequestpkcs7-initializefromcertificate

Comment: First of all thank you for taking your time and replaying! Back to the question, I tried using the IX509CertificateRequestPkcs7:: InitalizeFromCertificate but the problem is that i dont have access to the private key and only have the original CSR used to issue the current certificate. So i tried to use InitalizeFromCertificate and InitalizeDecode and combine the 2 somehow but I had no success so far. Any ideas on how to combat the problem?

Comment: if you don't have original private key, you cannot perform renewal, because you don't have a key to sign renewal request. Having original CSR doesn't give you anything. Either, retrieve original private key or start from over. I voted to close this question, because it is too vague. Please, improve your question to include all necessary details and what you have tried so far.